# Why json values return with null, despite i assigned specific value to them?

Tags: json, parsing, null

I have a database, which have a table with a lot of variables. I convert it into json. I checked the output on an online json parser, and there are some variables which have null value, despite i assigned them my own value, and i claimed it NOT to be NUll. The working ones(which show the values i gave to them) absolutely was made like the other ones which aren't working, so we could say the problem is random. Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

put mysqli_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8') before SELECT query solved the problem :)